# How to update document in MongoDB through Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update my document field with the following code, but I catch an error `"Cannot GET /updation"`.

My code:

```js
router.put('/updation', (req, res) => {
  const query = { email: "babra@arzepak.com" };
  const newEmail = { $set: { name: "babra", email: "nadralatif952@gmail.com" } };

  Registration.updateOne()
    .then((registration) => {
      console.log("updating");
      res.render('index', { title: 'updating registrations', registrations });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.send('Sorry! Something went wrong.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong Method

In your router you registered a route `'/updation'` for `PUT` method.
Hence only request with method `PUT` will be handled by your router. The error `Cannot GET /updation` means you are trying to handle a request with `GET` method which is simply not registered by your router.

**A** - If this code is supposed to get triggered when you visit the page via browser, then you should register the route for `GET` method, like `router.get('/updation', ... )`,

or

**B** - If this code is supposed to run seperate from your view (like a REST API should), then use a `PUT` request and end the request inside your router with `res.status(200).json(yourdata)`

---

**Sidenote** :
It looks like you did not completely setup your mongoose query, I mean you defined the query but you don't use it in the database request. To use the defined query you propbably should change your code, according to the mongoose docs : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne . I am not including a specific code example here, since it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

send a request with `PUT` method  and you didn't use of `query` and `newEmail` as arguments for `updateOne()` pass them, and in new version of mongoose you don't need to `$set` for updating so change your code like this :

```
router.put('/updation', (req, res) => {
  const query = { email: "babra@arzepak.com" }
  const newEmail =  { name: "babra", email: "nadralatif952@gmail.com" } 
  Registration.updateOne(query,newEmail)
      .then((registration) => {
          console.log("updating")
          res.render('index', { title: 'updating registrations', registrations });
      })
      .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry! Something went wrong.'); });
  })
```